# ¿Cómo puedo cargar registros de una base de datos en un jComboBox y un jTextField?

Tags: java, mysql, poo

Saludos he creado esta tabla en mi base de datos.

Ejemplo:
tabla productos con las columnas idproducto, producto, precio.

Y quiero cargar los datos del producto en un combobox y un textfield si entonces si  el producto es producto1 entonces que cargue su  precio en un textfield.

Por lo que cree este método:

```
private void llenaComboBox() {

        try {
            sAccess = "select producto,precio from productos";
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sAccess);
            ResultSet ver = pst.executeQuery();
            while (ver.next()) {
                modelocombo.addElement(ver.getString("producto"));
                cboexamen.setModel(modelocombo);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmdetalleFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

    }
```

Pero todavía no resuelvo la carga del precio del producto en el textfield.
Para ser cargado en mi formulario detallefactura.

De antemano gracias por tomarse la molestia de orientarme.

Comment: Puedes guardar en el combobox un mapa de objetos completos con todos los datos de cada registro, y luego agregas un listener al combobox y allí obtienes cualquier valor. Eso lo puedes hacer no solamente con el precio, sino con cualquier otro valor. [Mira este ejemplo](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/JComboBox/Store_Key_Value_Pair_to_JCombobox.htm). El combo guarda objetos `Student` completos. Y en el `actionPerformed` se obtiene el `id`... como se podría obtener el nombre o cualquier otro dato del `Student` seleccionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas obtiendo un numero de registros de la base de datos,mas de 1, y vas a añadir uno de los campos a una lista del combobox,y otro de los campos a un Textfield, tendras que tener en cuenta que una cosa es almacenar todos los campos de tu columna en el combo box, y otra distinta es comprobar que valor tiene el combobox y para mostrar en tu Textfield el precio segun el combo box.
Aclarado esto, yo te recomendaria que almacenaras los precios en un array a la par que los almacenas en tu combobox, ya asi tan solo tendria que hacer la comprobacion del valor del combo box y cuando coincida puedes realizas el SetText correspondiente en el Textfield.

```
int precios [];
int contador=0;
private void llenaComboBox() {

        try {
            sAccess = "select producto,precio from productos";
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sAccess);
            ResultSet ver = pst.executeQuery();
            while (ver.next()) {

                modelocombo.addElement(ver.getString("producto"));
                precios[contador]=ver.getInt("precio");
                contador++;
                cboexamen.setModel(modelocombo);


            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmdetalleFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

    }
```

Ya cuando tengas que recuperar el valor en el textfield, tan solo tendras que indicar que el indice del combobox es el mismo que el valor del array que deseas recuperar.

Comment: Gracias por la orientación.